# Self Tracking Entities not returning modified object

Tags: c#, wcf, self-tracking-entities

I have the following function to update and insert a record in the table

```
public DASInput UpdateDASInputTable(DASInput fileSetData, Guid programID)
    {
        string connectionString = GetConnectionString(programID);
        BI_ProgramConfigurationEntities dataContext = new BI_ProgramConfigurationEntities(connectionString);

        dataContext.DASInputs.ApplyChanges(fileSetData);
        dataContext.SaveChanges(System.Data.Objects.SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave);
        fileSetData = dataContext.DASInputs.FirstOrDefault();

        return fileSetData;
    }
```

When I make first call with a new object of type DASInput, then it gets inserted correctly in the database. (DASInput table has the primary key as int with identity specification on).

But this first time insertion does not return the modified value of the primary key of the DASInput table.

So on every subsequent call a new record gets inserted in the database. I want the primary key(self generated by DB) to be returned to the client when the record gets inserted.

Comment: I have also read below article, for considerations about self tracking entities. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407090.aspx               But it do not elaborate more on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the syntax for adding an entity into a linq controlled database more along the lines of :

```
context.Table.AddObject(newStore);
//or
context.Table.Add(newStore);

context.SaveChanges();
```

I do answer this tentatively, not being hugely knowledgeable on LINQ.

Comment: AddObject method inserts into the table explicitly and do not update the table

Comment: context.SaveChanges() will save the added entity to the database. If its an update you are looking for (as opposed to adding a new record) then just call context.SaveChanges(); and not the context.Table.Add(newStore) - as the entities are tracked from the context, this will update the properties, without adding a new entity to the database.